# How to vectorize labeled bigrams with scikit learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, scikit-learn, nltk

I'm self studying how to use scikit-learn and i decided to start the [second task](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html#where-to-from-here) but with my own corpus. I obtained some bigrams by hand, let's say:

```
training_data = [[('this', 'is'), ('is', 'a'),('a', 'text'), 'POS'],
[('and', 'one'), ('one', 'more'), 'NEG']
[('and', 'other'), ('one', 'more'), 'NEU']]
```

I would like to vectorize them in a format that nicely can be filled in some classification algorithm provided by scikit-learn (svc, multnomial naive bayes, etc). This is what i tried:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

count_vect = CountVectorizer(analyzer='word')

X = count_vect.transform(((' '.join(x) for x in sample)
                  for sample in training_data))

print X.toarray()
```

The problem with this is that i dont know how to treat the label (i.e. `'POS', 'NEG', 'NEU'`), do i need to "vectorize" the label too in order to pass the `training_data` to a classification algorithm or i just could let it like 'POS' or any other kind of string?. Another problem is that I'm getting this:

```
raise ValueError("Vocabulary wasn't fitted or is empty!")
ValueError: Vocabulary wasn't fitted or is empty!
```

So, how can i vectorize bigrams like `training_data`. I also was reading about [dictvectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer.html) and [Sklearn-pandas](https://github.com/paulgb/sklearn-pandas), do you guys think using them could be a better aproach for this task?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should look like this:

```
>>> training_data = [[('this', 'is'), ('is', 'a'),('a', 'text'), 'POS'],
                 [('and', 'one'), ('one', 'more'), 'NEG'],
                 [('and', 'other'), ('one', 'more'), 'NEU']]
>>> count_vect = CountVectorizer(preprocessor=lambda x:x,
                                 tokenizer=lambda x:x)
>>> X = count_vect.fit_transform(doc[:-1] for doc in training_data)

>>> print count_vect.vocabulary_
{('and', 'one'): 1, ('a', 'text'): 0, ('is', 'a'): 3, ('and', 'other'): 2, ('this', 'is'): 5, ('one', 'more'): 4}
>>> print X.toarray()
[[1 0 0 1 0 1]
 [0 1 0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 1 0 1 0]]
```

Then put your labels in a target variable:

```
y = [doc[-1] for doc in training_data] # ['POS', 'NEG', 'NEU']
```

Now you can train a model:

```
model = SVC()
model.fit(X, y)
```

Comment: I actually have been using that way of seting lables. The problem is that i have a bigger list of bigrams and it doesnt look clear how is scikit learn using the labels to train and predict some result. Is there another pythonic way to set labels instead of doing it line by line?. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, updated my answer, also fixed the `CountVectorizer` call so that it doesn't preprocesses or tokenizes your bigrams.

Comment: There are several small mistakes in your code, I recommend you open a new question related to the error you are getting now and the ones you are about to get (hint: compare your code for the labels `y` with mine)

Comment: Thanks for the feed back. I all ready fixed the issue. Could you explain me in more detail how happened the labeling?.

Comment: If you mean "how to extract the last element from a list of list", that is called a list comprehension in python. Similar to `y=[]; for sublist in data_training: y.append(sublist[-1]);`, where `sublist[-1]` means "the last element of sublist"

Comment: Thanks, i didnt realize the compression.

Comment: I tried to do the same procedure to see what happen with `HashingVectorizer` as follows:`from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import HashingVectorizer
vect = HashingVectorizer(preprocessor=lambda x:x,tokenizer=lambda x:x)
X = vect.transform(doc[:-1] for doc in training_data)` but i get:`TypeError: feature names must be strings`, why is this happening?

Comment: May I ask why are your data bigrams and not raw text? All vectorizers in scikit learn expect a list of raw text. Thats why I had to make the lambda hack to accommodate for your unusual use case.

Comment: Sure, because i thought that the standard way was the one that I ask in the above question, I just wanted to know if it's possible to control how is vectorizing scikit-learn. Thanks fot the response.

Comment: Also, if I read a list of raw text this will turn on unigrams insted of bigrams that's why I would like to handle words as bigrams not unigrams

Comment: Well `CountVectorizer` can take raw text in and output bigrams, look up the `ngram_range` parameter.